# Django + Celery: how to chain tasks with parameters to periodic task

Tags: python, django, celery, cron, periodic-task

I have configured Django + Celery: all works, i can execute tasks, that called from views.py i.e. `mul.apply_async((2, 5), queue='celery', countdown=5)`

I need to shedule periodic task that will chain simple tasks with argument that passed from users.
I read docs http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/canvas.html and know how to chain, i know how to make periodic task without parameters `@periodic_task(run_every=(crontab(hour="*", minute="*", day_of_week="*")))`

But how to combine this?

What i want workflow:

1. User creates project with parameters. 5 tasks executed, using that parameters.
2. Then i need shedule to repeat all 5 tasks every 24 hours. So here i dont know how to pass parameters (they save to db).

In other answer i saw this syntax:

```
CELERYBEAT_SCHEDULE = {
# crontab(hour=0, minute=0, day_of_week='saturday')
'schedule-name': {  # example: 'file-backup' 
    'task': 'some_django_app.tasks....',  # example: 'files.tasks.cleanup' 
    'schedule': crontab(...)
    'args': (2, 3)
},
```

}

But the problem here is that it located in settings.py of Django but not in tasks.py and i cannot dynamically pass args.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The celerybeat task you register could be a wrapper and perform the project/task logic inside of it, firing off other tasks as appropriate.  You could fetch the project tasks inside of your celery beat job.

- `CELERYBEAT_SCHEDULE.task` -> `'some_django_app.project_beat_task'`

Then project beat task could retrieve the correct projects and all tasks associated with them, perhaps spawning a chain of tasks for each project